# "not well-formed (invalid token): " error for trying to parse an XML file

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am having this error. I am trying to access an xmlfile called "people-kb.xml".

I am having the problem on a line known as: `xmldoc = minidom.parse(xmlfile) #Accesses file.`

xmldoc is "people-kb.xml" which is passed into a method such as:

```
parseXML('people-kb.xml')
```

So the problem I was having came from the save file I had created as I was trying to make a multiple trials that would contain information on two people. for now I only have one trial included and not multiple yet as I am starting with creating the file and after I would edit if it already exists.
the code for making the file is:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

def saveXML(xmlfile):
    root = ET.Element("Simulation")
    ET.SubElement(root, "chaserStartingCoords").text = "1,1"
    ET.SubElement(root, "runnerStartingCoords").text = "9,9"

    doc = ET.SubElement(root, "trail")
    ET.SubElement(doc, "number").text = "1"
    doc1 = ET.SubElement(doc, "number", name="number").text = "1" #Trying to make multiple trials

    ET.SubElement(doc1, "chaserEndCoords").text = "10,10"
    ET.SubElement(doc1, "runnerInitialCoords").text = "10,10"
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write(xmlfile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        saveXML('output.xml')
```

Where it says "`number`" I am trying to make it the amount of trials it would be. So what I am trying to make it expect is an output like this:

```
<simulation>
  <chaserStartingCoords>1,1<chaserStartingCoords>
  <runnerStartingCoords>9,9<runnerStartingoords>
  <trial>
     <number>1</number>
     <move number="1">
       <chaserEndcoords>10,10<chaserEndCoords>
       <runnerInitialCoords>10,10<runnerInitialCoords>
       </move>
  </trial>
</simulation>
```

I've been having a problem trying to get the `<move number="1">` part as later I expect to be able to go into the file and iterate through each node called "`move`" to check positions.

Comment: Problem sound like it is with the content of the XML file. I suggest you find and on-line XML validator and run the file through it.

Comment: I am new to it, there is however when trying to name a node of the file, it shows a red highlight on "1"

Comment: You will need to put the offending XML in your question — no one can help you based on the minimal information you've provided.

Comment: Forsure, I will edit the question and show what I am trying to do

Comment: You need to learn about closing tags. For example, a closing tag for the tag `<a>` is `</a>`. Change your code accordingly. And, **important**, the count of opening tags and closing tags in the whole XML file has to be the same.

Comment: The output you want to make it expect isn't valid XML format. If that is not what you're trying to read then we need s a sample of the *actual* `people-kb.xml` file that's is causing the problem. I thought that was what you were going to add. Regardless, please don't vandalize your question again. If you no longer want help, just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You say "when trying to name a node of the file, it shows a red highlight on "1" "

That suggests you're trying to use "1", or something beginning with "1", as an element or attribute name, which would be invalid.